# How to execute an angularJs function after DOM is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working with google map & angularJS, i want to excecute the distance between current location and another location in JSON file. But the distance only show when I have a button in view template, that call a function in angular JS via ng-click:

```
<button id="show-distance" ng-click="showDistance()">Show Distance</button>
```

in AngularJS file:

```
$scope.showDistance = function(){
    jQuery.each($scope.items, function (index, value) {
        $scope.distance = $scope.getDistance(jQuery.cookie('currentLat'), jQuery.cookie('currentLng'), value['latitude'], value['longitude']);
        value['location'] = $scope.distance;
    });
}
```

I show the distance in this way:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid" class="data-table">
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Store name')?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Address')?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->__('Distance')?></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | limitTo:quantity " ng-controller="ItemController" class="list-locator">
        <td ng-click="open(item)">{{item.title}}</span></td>
        <td ng-click="open(item)">{{item.address}}</td>
        <td ng-click="open(item)">{{item.location}} miles</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What can I do to show the distance without clicking anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call this block in a controller tied to your view

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      jQuery.each($scope.items, function (index, value) {
                    $scope.distance = $scope.getDistance(jQuery.cookie('currentLat'), jQuery.cookie('currentLng'), value['latitude'], value['longitude']);
                    value['location'] = $scope.distance;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controller function to execute your code.

```
function MainControl($scope) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            $scope.distance = $scope.getDistance(jQuery.cookie('currentLat'), jQuery.cookie('currentLng'), value['latitude'], value['longitude']);
            value['location'] = $scope.distance;
        });
    }
```

Comment: I just try and nothing happened, I think the problem is angularJS can't get current location.